# Ember: How can I pass multiple parameters to route through params

Tags: ember.js

```
//router.js

Router.map(function(){
    this.route('posts');
    this.route('profile' { path: '/profile/:id1/:id2' });
});
```

I want to pass two id's to the profile route some how. Is that possible?
tell me a solution to do it. also tell how should I set the `profile/route.js` file

or can I make a request like `localhost:4200/profile/?id1=somevalue&id2=somevalue` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass multiple params using `dynamic segments` in Emberjs.
You can use `link-to` helper like:

```
{{link-to "go to profile page" "profile" myid1 myid2}}
```

And in your profile route, you can get passed parameters in route's `model` like:

```
model: function(dto){
    return {
        id1: dto.id1,
        id2: dto.id2
    };
}
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a0ae706858a1a1c959d4d033afc42560) for this usage.